# How to set image control properties that belong to a class?

Tags: c#, image, oop, class, controls

I have an image control as one of the properties of a class.

```
    public Image ImageControl
    {
        get
        {
            return _imgControl;
        }

        set
        {
            _imgControl = value;
        }

    }
```

In the class constructor, is it correct to use this

```
        ImageControl.Width = bi.PixelWidth;
        ImageControl.Height = bi.PixelHeight;
        ImageControl.Source = bi;
```

or this?

```
        _imgControl.Width = bi.PixelWidth;
        _imgControl.Height = bi.PixelHeight;
        _imgControl.Source = bi;
```

I am just wondering because ImageControl itself is a control which contains properties, how does it affect the value of _imageControl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageControl` property just returns `_imgControl` so when you are working with the former, you are in fact working with the latter. In your scenario, there is no difference. Altough answering to your question in general, I would preffer use the field syntax in the constructor, because the property may impact the state of the current instance which may be not initialized yet.